# Pricing and operation concerns for Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

My knowledge regarding servers is limited and I'm trying to figure learn more. I'm currently looking into EC2 and I have a question regarding their 'hours of runtime' for a single instance.

Say I go with an m1.medium instance which is $0.120 per hour. Is there any kind of underlying meaning to that? Or is it literally, if my server is working on something 24/7 for a month (31 days) that I'll be billed at $89.28 (24 * .120 * 31)? If I have an unusually high period of activity I don't want to receive a $1000 bill because I didn't fully understand the server pricing.

Also, would 2 m1.small instances perform about the same as 1 m1.medium instance, or is the relationship not entirely linear?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Amazon's pricing system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those $89.28 are indeed money billed for a month of ec2.medium instance usage. But you also should be aware of

- DataTransfer costs (for example, if you host a web application, amout of data served to your end users is billed)
- Storage price, as your instance should have some storage, same applies for backups (for example in form of snapshots, they are billed for space used)

You also might be billed for other services (such as EMR), but just in case you use them, so no need to worry right from the start.

Refer to [EC2 price](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/) or [price calculator](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html)

If you worry about unexpected bills, set up [a billing alert](http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/). You'll be notified if your bill exceeds your expectations.

As for performance, 2 m1.small is roughly equal to m1.medium only in terms of CPU, but performance often depends on IO, architecture (32b vs 64b) and other factors. I had a use case when t1.micro instance outperformed m1.medium.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did previously check out the price calculator, but I couldn't make sense of all the fields, not to mention some of them I honestly can't estimate at the moment.

Comment: understood, had similar feelings few years ago :)